# Is it better to have multiple media queries for different element, or different widths?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm creating a responsive site, and I'm currently making some media queries. I write them as I go, like this for example:

```
.status-reply-disabled {
color: #B1B1B1;
font-size: 14px;
margin-top: 10px;
position: absolute;
margin-left: 65px;  
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .status-reply-disabled {
        font-size: 10px;
        margin-left: 35px;  
    }
}
```

then a little later I'll have something like this:

```
.status-reply-avatar {
border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;  
width: 45px;
border-radius: 50%;
position: absolute;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .status-reply-avatar {
        display:none;   
    }
}
```

Would it be better, for processing times, to have all media queries of, say, 600px in one big querie? Like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .status-reply-avatar {
        display:none;   
    }
    .status-reply-disabled {
        font-size: 10px;
        margin-left: 35px;  
    }

    ...

    All other styles for this width

    ...

}
```

or is what I'm doing fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a HUGE amount of code, it doesn't really matter concerning performance. Lately I prefer to write media several media queries, always close to the general rule of a particular element, simply to keep control over things (like in your first two codeblocks). I actually like that more. In terms of speed if wont make much difference.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference at all. In terms of organization, you could code like you were doing before and organize your code in sections, or create another CSS file only for media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, place your code in one media query, it will do the same thing and you will write less rows of code, and you will follow the **DRY** principle (Don't Repeat Yourself).

If you define the same media query twice in one file, it's not a very good practice...

Answer (score -1):

Try to put all the code together under a specific query, say max-width=600px. This is better for a clean and semantic code. Go from desktop to the narrower screen which is for the mobile say around 400px. Its always better. You'll confuse if you come back at it after a week or so. Start wide and then narrow as you go. Don't code for an element in max-width=600px if you still didn't do the 900px stop.

Comment: It is more important to think mobile-first, so from the smallest media-query to the biggest, smartphone then tablet then computer to make it simple.